# Actual, open and good functional programming language

Tags: node.js, open-source, functional-programming

I've been programming C# for quite some time now and the best part of it is its functional components - delegates, events, etc. C# is very inefficient when it comes to that and I was wondering if anyone could tell me what is a good functional languages. It must be free(open), have - big, or not - community.

I really liked node.js for its event driven and friendly for JavaScript developers.

Any more arguments for node.js, or for any other language?

Comment: Node.js is written with JavaScript. So if you're looking to expand your skills, learning Node.js makes a lot of sense because you are also learning JavaScript, which is a very valuable skill now-a-days (Sorry, ActionScript 3!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my very personal opinion, you might want to take a look at erlang.

It has very clear syntax, good documentation, and nice courses. There is a community and it has been actually used in real-life commercial applications. Unlike other languages that have never managed the step to leave universities or very small and specialized user circles.

I am not saying that other functional languages don't share maybe these same advantages, but erlang is a good point to start looking.

For starters, look at the stackoverflow questions tagged with "erlang" and you can get a first impression.